# How to use pigpio to control 3 stepper motors with drivers

Tags: pigpio

I need to control 3 independent stepper motors with stepper motor drivers using RPi.

Driver of each motor requires STEP pulse to make one step (let's not bother about DIR and ENABLE signals for now).

Basic goals:

slowly accelerate (with a ramp of pulses) to desired speed of stepping;

maintain acquired stepping speed (max is about 5000 steps per second);

change speed with slow acceleration or deceleration.

This have to be controllable for each motor individually.

For now I have managed to do this for just one motor using the information from this question (thank you, Joan!): [how to generate smooth frequency ramp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26216/how-to-generate-smooth-frequency-ramp)

It works just fine, but I'm stuck with how to do this on 3 different GPIO pins.

Is there a way for transmitting 3 different waveforms on 3 different pins simultaneously?

Thank you.